# Netty open channels Benchmark fails

Tags: apache, netty, benchmarking

Here is some code:

```
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
        //ctx.close();
    }
```

I'm trying to test my server with apache -ab command. When ctx.close() is uncommented apache benchmark command "ab -c100 -n1000" executes normally, but when channel remains opened benchmark shows 70007 Timeout Exception. How can i keep all my connections opened?

Answer (score 2):

You should close the Channel only if keep-alive header is not present and only once the response was full written. See the HttpHelloWorldServer example

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/helloworld/HttpHelloWorldServerHandler.java